# Count foreign objects for model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have following models (simplified) in Django app:

```
class Company(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Event(BaseModel):
    company= models.ForeignKey(Company)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description", blank=True,null=True,max_length=200,default="")
```

in one of my views, I want to count Event objects for company "owned" by logged user.
to access company object I use something like request.user.company

How can I count all Event objects related to single company?

## EDIT:

I think I asked wrong question. What I want to do:
I select single event object:

```
event = Event.objects.get(uuid=event_uuid)
```

and now I want to get number of Event but within single company, not global ID.

Comment: write data sample and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found hard to understand your question, do you want to count `Event` associated to a given `Company`?

```
c = Company.objects.get(...)
event_n = Event.objects.filter(company=c).count()
```

or

```
n = 2
event_n = Event.objects.filter(company__pk=n).count()
```

or

```
u = User.objects.get(...)
event_n = Event.objects.filter(company__user=u).count()
```

Do you want to collect one (some) company (companies) with the number of `Event` associated?

```
from django.db.models import Count
company = Company.objects.filter(pk=n).annotate(event_n=Count('event')).get()
print company.event_n
```

or

```
companies = Company.objects.filter(...).annotate(event_n=Count('event'))
for c in companies:
    print c.event_n
```

If you already have an event and you want the number of events associated to its company you can try

```
e = Event.objects.get(...)
event_n = Event.objects.filter(company=e.company).count()
```

or

```
n = 3
e = Event.objects.filter(pk=n).annotate(event_n=Count('company__event')).get()
print e.event_n
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.
So, I have several Company objects. Each of them has multiple events.
When I show single event, I want to display number of this single event (not count) within parent company.
Example:
I have
Event1 assigned to Company1
Event2 assigned to Company2
Event3 assigned to Company1

then, when displaying Event3 I want to show "ID:2"

Comment: An example id/primary key of your `Event`. Instead of `pk=3` you can use `uuid=event_uuid` or whatever you like.